# Nifi Getting specific column value from getHbase result

Tags: json, hbase, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from Hbase using GetHBase process and the result is as below

```
{
  "row" : "r5",
  "cells" : {
    "cf1:ABC:" : "V1",
    "cf1:DEF" : "V2",
    "cf1:HIJ" : "V3",
    "cf1:KLM" : "V4"
  }
}
```

Now, I want to filter the json for specific columns

expected result
`{"DEF":"V2","KLM":"V4"}`

Flow tried

GetHbase --> evaluateJsonPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html), set `Jolt Transformation DSL` as `Shift` and set `Jolt Specification` as:

```
{
      "cells": {
        "cf1:DEF": "DEF",
        "cf1:KLM": "KLM"
      }
}
```

this will transform your input json into your desired json.

[Jolt Transform](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) is an open source library that helps you transform Json documents using other Json documents as specification.

If you'd like to parameterize them, you can do that using parameters using NiFi 1.10.0 like so:

```
{
      "cells": {
        "cf1:#{param1}": "#{param1}",
        "cf1:#{param2}": "#{param2}"
      }
}
```

Or using NiFi 1.4.0+ with [expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) and the [variable registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Variables) like so:

```
{
      "cells": {
        "cf1:${param1}": "${param1}",
        "cf1:${param2}": "${param2}"
      }
}
```

Everything is linked to a documentation so you can read about it all :)

Comment: i want values to be dynamic.
{
      "cells": {
        "cf1:DEF": "@val",
        "cf1:KLM": "@val"
      }
}
tried with this specification, but getting null in result

Comment: how so? please explain it in your question. You've stated you wanted "specific" columns..

Comment: Do you mean to their own column name? like `{"cf1:DEF":"DEF", "cf1:KLM":"KLM"}`?

Comment: i am expecting result as {"DEF":"V2","KLM":"V4"}

Comment: able to generate result by using the specification you provided, just confused little bit, as i am just started with nifi

Comment: can we create any generic specification for this scenario, if column family and columns names changes in future?

Comment: I've added more details to my answer